# How to pass parameters to an existing method?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a button that uses Process.Start to initiate a process along with a parameter, although how could you let the user define this parameter ("C:\Documents"), e.g. possibly a text box that a user enters it in and then directs the input into the command?

Code so far:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("increase.exe", "C:\\Documents");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the existence of a `myTextBox` textbox on the form, you simply access its `Text` attribute to retrieve the value:

```
Process.Start("increase.exe", myTextBox.Text);
```

Of course, without validating that this is an existing path (and the user has permissions to it), you will get an exception.

Comment: @Tamzin - Sure. I suggest you read the MSDN documentation for it.